# Android.Views.InflateException when changing ImageView

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am getting the title error when starting my `Xamarin.Android` application. I started from the "Navigation Drawer App" template.

The error is thrown in `MainActivity.cs` on line `SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);` in the `OnCreate` method:

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity, NavigationView.IOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
    {
        readonly DataAccess dataAccess = new DataAccess();
        private List<ResultSummary> data;
        private ResultsSummaryListAdapter adapter;

        protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main); //Error here
            Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
            SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            DrawerLayout drawer = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, Resource.String.navigation_drawer_open, Resource.String.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.AddDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.SyncState();

            NavigationView navigationView = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.nav_view);
            navigationView.SetNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        }

       //Other default code

}
```

This starting occurring after I tried to change some of the default images. As a result, I have tracked down the issue to the `ImageView` in `nav_header_main.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    //If I remove this ImageView it works fine.
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/RunnerName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="Runner Name Here" />

</LinearLayout>
```

If I replace the images in the `mipmap-` folders with the defaults, it works again.

From what I've read the issue is because one of the images is too large. Is that correct, or is it possibly something else wrong the image(s)?

This is a bit confusing because I created my images from [Android Asset Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html) using the "Launcher icon generator" so I would expect that creates appropriately sized icons. I replaced the images with the same name so it's not a referencing error; if it was I'd get a different exception.

Any ideas on what's going on here?

Comment: I test the same code with large image, works well with no error. I could not reproduce error, could you provide more details?

Comment: I think the problem was caused when I deleted the default `ic_launcher_foreground.png` and `ic_launcher_round.png` files. Even when I added them back in, I was still getting the error, but perhaps I needed to clear out a cache somewhere. In the end I "fixed" it by removing my images and replacing with all defaults, doing a bunch of Clean Build and deleting of files from bin folders, restarting VS and getting it to build. Then I replaced all of the default images with my own which, as of right now, is working. Perhaps I need to find out properly how and where those images are used.

Comment: I try to delete the desault `ic_launcher_foreground.png` and `ic_launcher_round.png` files, still works well. Android provides different versions of the mipmap folder to handle launcher icons of different densities. Sometimes, maybe you project does not accept the changes well. Delete the bin and obj folder to clean and rebuils always be useful. I am glad you solvd the probelm.